# Fatal Error for Chromium

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, chromium-embedded

I am getting an error when i run my app from archive. Unable to understand this :(

```
Jun 21 11:13:55 NOIMAC61 MyBrowser[26324]: [0621/111355.058483:ERROR:mach_port_broker.mm(100)] bootstrap_check_in: Permission denied (1100)
Jun 21 11:13:55 NOIMAC61 MyBrowser[26324]: [0621/111355.095394:ERROR:mach_broker_mac.mm(52)] Failed to initialize the MachListenerThreadDelegate
Jun 21 11:13:55 NOIMAC61 MyBrowser[26324]: [0621/111354.159264:FATAL:file_path_watcher_kqueue.cc(255)] Check failed: last_entry != 0 (0 vs. 0)
    0   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000011eaecfee _ZN4base5debug10StackTraceC2Ev + 30
    1   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000011eaed065 _ZN4base5debug10StackTraceC1Ev + 21
    2   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000011eb73520 _ZN7logging10LogMessageD2Ev + 80
    3   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000011eb71085 _ZN7logging10LogMessageD1Ev + 21
    4   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000011eb29ff1 _ZN4base21FilePathWatcherKQueue5WatchERKNS_8FilePathEbRKNS_8CallbackIFvS3_bELNS_8internal8CopyModeE1ELNS6_10RepeatModeE1EEE + 1441
    5   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000011eb2e35e _ZN4base12_GLOBAL__N_119FilePathWatcherImpl5WatchERKNS_8FilePathEbRKNS_8CallbackIFvS4_bELNS_8internal8CopyModeE1ELNS7_10RepeatModeE1EEE + 2238
    6   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000011eb20ee3 _ZN4base15FilePathWatcher5WatchERKNS_8FilePathEbRKNS_8CallbackIFvS3_bELNS_8internal8CopyModeE1ELNS6_10RepeatModeE1EEE + 515
    7   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000012109e6f2 _ZN3net8internal21DnsConfigServicePosix7Watcher5WatchEv + 722
    8   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000012109e3ab _ZN3net8internal21DnsConfigServicePosix13StartWatchingEv + 523
    9   Chromium Embedded Framework         0x00000001210997b3 _ZN3net16DnsConfigService11WatchConfigERKN4base8CallbackIFvRKNS_9DnsConfigEELNS1_8internal8CopyModeE1ELNS7_10RepeatModeE1EEE + 595
    10  Chromium Embedded Framework         0x0000000120e4e1c0 _ZN3net24NetworkChangeNotifierMac22DnsConfigServiceThread4InitEv + 800
    11  Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000011ed8012e _ZN4base6Thread10ThreadMainEv + 3310
    12  Chromium Embedded Framework         0x000000011ed5f821 _ZN4base12_GLOBAL__N_110ThreadFuncEPv + 705
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffaf694aab _pthread_body + 180
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffaf6949f7 _pthread_body + 0
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fffaf694221 thread_start + 13
Jun 21 11:13:55 NOIMAC61 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.es.test.7764[26324]): Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5 sent by exc handler[0]
```

Comment: y a downvote without any reason? these error somehow help others too.. i believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer

I am using a script that moves the chromium framework from one location to another.
This script fetched the framework from DEBUG Folder instead of the RELEASE FOLDER.

Path is updated and it worked!!!!